# Getting custom response from twilio

Tags: parameters, twilio, call

I am using twilio to call, in my laravel application. I have used webhook for that. When i click call button in web browser, it calls to specific phone number and when called user presses any digit, I get the digit as a response in webhook. I want to send question_id as parameter to twilio application and when user presses digit 3 in his phone. I will store 3 as answer along with the question_id in my db.
for exmple:
question_id: 1, Press 1 for sales, press 2 for account or press 3 for operator service

received digit: 3,
I have to store 1 as question_id and 3 as call_response in my db

Comment: Could you please share your code where you're specifically facing issues?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to build an [Interactive Voice Response](https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-is-ivr) (IVR) and that you only want to store the information on the pressed keys during the call - so you wouldn't need an actual database and could leverage the same by using [Twilio Studio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/tutorials/how-to-build-an-ivr). It's also possible to make an HTTP request to your application at the end of the Studio flow and store all the pressed keys with one call to the database.

Suppose Studio doesn't offer all the functionality you need. In that case, it might be worth checking out our [serverless offering](https://www.twilio.com/docs/serverless/functions-assets/functions) and the [Sync API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sync/quickstart/js) to store information for a limited or unlimited time.

Comment: I have to fetch instructions from database and call. Does IVR system allows that, and does IVR flow starts only from incoming call?, I have to start the flow from outgoing call. Thanks for this guidance

Comment: IVR is the name of user experience and is not a technical term. So yes, you can use any types of https request and triggers for an IVR

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please accept this comment here. The comment adding section is saying too long characters for commenting. My code is like this:

```
public function twilio_webhook() {
    $response = new VoiceResponse();
    $phone_number = $_POST['To'];
    $option_digit = $_POST['Digits'];
    $country = $_POST['ToCountry'];
    $call_status = '1';

    CallResponse::insert([
        'phone_number' => $phone_number,
        'option_digit' => $option_digit,
        'country' => $country,
        'call_status' => $call_status
    ]);

    if(array_key_exists('Digits', $_POST)) {
        switch($_POST['Digits']) {
            case 1:
                $response->say('Thank you for calling our sales department!');
            break;
            case 2:
                $response->say('Thank you for calling our account team!');
            break;
            case 3:
                $response->say('Thank you for calling our operator service team!');
            break;
            default:
                $response->say('Please try again later!');
            break;
        }
        header('Content-type: text/xml');
    }
    echo $response;
}
```

I am hardcoding the response here, thank you for calling sales department. This code assumes that, call has said, Press 1 for sales department. This function works well for this case. But there are several instructions in database. What if the call instruction has said, press 1 for connecting to the technical department. Got the pressed digit, but don't know what was the question...

Comment: StackOverflow keeps the comment section short on purpose to avoid that someone adds long snippets in there. The right way forward would be to edit your original question with the code you added here :)